# Asp.net MVC application and get JSON result from database and input it to google cloud translation v2 and get json result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, google-translation-api

I need to send 2000 words at a time as a json file to google cloud translation api V2 and get a json result from the api for all the words at once. Is that possible. If yes, please provide any sample ASP.NET MVC 5 code for .NET framework 4.5 in C#

Comment: No, you will not get code sample here.

Comment: Hi Thangadurai,Are you saying its not possible or it is possible but i cant get code sample

Comment: In SO, usually you will get solutions for a specific issue that you encounter in your programming. Posts that asks suggestions on a topic that is too broad or asking to provide code help/sample will be ignored by most, and it is off-topic.

Comment: Okay..Understood..Thank you..Im a new user to SO.